# Sending ajax request for each element?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an app that has rows, each row contains data. The rows are created by the user (just cloning a sample row).

My ajax function looks like this.

```
save : function(el) {

        //Renaming the properties to match the row index and organize 
        jQuery('#application-builder-layout .builder-row').each(function(row) {

                // Iterate over the properties
                jQuery(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {

                    // Save original name attr to element's data
                    jQuery(this).data('name', jQuery(this).attr('name') );

                    // Rewrite the name attr
                    jQuery(this).attr('name', 'application[rows]['+row+'][elements]['+jQuery(this).attr('name')+']');

                });

        });


        //Looping through each row and saving them seperately with new rowkey
        setTimeout(function() {

            // Iterate over the layers
            jQuery('#application-builder-layout .row-box').each(function(row) {

                // Reindex layerkey
                jQuery(this).find('input[name="rowkey"]').val(row);

                // Data to send
                $data = jQuery('#application-builder-layout .row-box').eq(row).find('input, textarea, select');
                //$data = $data.add( jQuery('#application-builder-layout')  );

                jQuery.ajax(jQuery('#form').attr('action'), {
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : $data.serialize(),
                    async : false,
                    success: function( response ) {
                      //console.log( response );  
                    }
                });

            });

        }, 500);

},
```

This is the jQuery, it's application style format so this function is inside a var and is called inside a submit function, the problem is not the ajax, looking at it in the console it saves the data fine, just like I have before.

**The Problem** I cant get all the data into the database (only the last ajax request) take a look below at *"Form Data"* it shows what my ajax data looks like and how it's inserting into the DB vs how it should insert, I am using json encode and usually this works, but recently I switched to OOP style coding in PHP so I am not sure if that changes anything?

**The PHP:**

```
class MyApp {

    const Post_Type = 'page';

    public function __construct() {
        // register actions
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
    }

    public function init() {
        // Initialize Post Type
        add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save_post'));
    }


    //The main save method
    public function save_post($post_id) {

        // Empty the builder
        if($_POST['rowkey'] == 0) {
            $builder = array();
        }

        $builder['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']] = $_POST['application']['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']];

        $builder = esc_sql(json_encode($builder));

        if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
                return;
        }

        if($_POST['post_type'] == self::Post_Type && current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {

                        // Update the post's meta field
                        update_post_meta($post_id, 'MY_DATABASE', $builder);

        } else {

                return;

        } 
    }


}
```

The above works fine, except its not inserting the data as an array just inserting the last ajax post call, not each. I am sure in my save method I need to reconfig that somehow, but I am just hacking away and cant find info on the web, so I could really use some insight.

I hope I provided enough.

**My code summed up:** Just to be clear on whats going on here, let me you some basic HTML of my app.

```
//This gets cloned and the jQuery renames the rowkey to match the index.
<div class="row-box">
    <input type="hidden" name="rowkey" value="0">
    <div class="builder-row">
        <textarea style="display: block;" name="html"></textarea>
        <textarea style="display: block;" name="breakingbad"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

So summed up lets say there is 4 rows, the jQuery renames each row, then loops through each and submits an ajax call for each of them. Then the PHP handles the $_POST, in prior applications working with my custom DB I got it to work but working with wp database I am having issues, maybe I am missing something in my method?

**Form Data:** the ajax form data looks like this (this is the form data inside headers which can be found in the console(firbug) or network(chrome))

```
//First element
rowkey:0
application[rows][0][elements][html]:A
application[rows][0][elements][breakingbad]:123
```

Then if there is another row ajax posts again

```
//Second element
rowkey:1
application[rows][1][elements][html]:B
application[rows][1][elements][breakingbad]:456
```

So an and so forth, the database looks like this

```
{"rows":{"2":{"elements":{"html":"B","breakingbad":"456"}}}}
```

It should be more like this

```
{"rows":[{"elements":{"html":"A","breakingbad":"123"},{"elements":{"html":"B","breakingbad":"456"}]}
```

**Holy Smokes Batman:** I think I got it, It all resides inside how I handle the `$_POST` ill update soon with an answer..

The database looks good like this

```
 {"rows":[
     {"elements":{"html":"A","breakingbad":"123"}},
     {"elements":{"html":"B","breakingbad":"456"}}]
 }
```

Now I can continue to build.. whew this was a MASSIVE headache.